# Appending a method to the Classify Function

Tags: neural-networks, paclets

Recently i created a color scheme and appended this to the relevant DataPaclet

```
clist = DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["TemperatureMap"]
myclist = 
 Reverse[Prepend[
   FoldList[Blend[{#, Green}, #2] &, clist[[10]], {10}/2], 
   clist[[13]]]]
mycolorFunc2 = Blend[myclist, #] &
AppendTo[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemeNames, \
"myColorFunction"]
```

Using the Function Classify, you can specify the method you would like to use, for example; "NeuralNetwork"

My question is more of a curiosity: Is it possible to append a method to the Classify function in the same way that i created a new color scheme?

For Example, If i created a Self-Normalizing Neural Network for numerical data and named it "MyMethod"; would i be able to append this to the Classify function such that i could use it  like this:

```
c=Classify[train,Method->"MyMethod"]
```